# GTK apps show "green" too dark

Tags: ubuntu, colors, gtk, gnome, gtk2

Using Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty, for whatever reason some GTK apps show things that should should be "green" as a color that is very close (but not identical) to "dark green". Wasn't able to see anything strange in the gtk themes, or X11 rgb.txt.
Several other colors don't look exactly right either.
Example in gvim:
[image: Screenshot of gvim, showing strange colors]

Another example happens in the GTK application `gitk`, where branch names in the revision tree use a dark green background color, instead of the normal bright green that it should be:
[image: Screenshot of gitk, showing dark green branch names]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix gitk, edit: `~/.config/git/gitk`

and change all occurances of *green* to *#00ff00*. Now the official new color is actually called *lime*, and *green* has been made identical to *darkgreen*, to make the *green* same as in Web colors (opposed to X11 colors). Someone had a brain fart obviously ([bug #744131](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=744131)). However I won't use *lime* but rather the hardcoded #00ff00, because my experience with these systems tells me that lime is bound to get fu**ed up by some other person's mood.

In particular, the branch name background is the entry: `set headbgcolor #00ff00`

If the file is empty or doesn't exist then you can simply create a file in place with that name and add that `headbgcolor` line to it.

All other tools that got broken by this bold change of the Tcl developers will need to be reconfigured similarly, if they allow it. Otherwise the applications will have to be changed, because Tcl devs seem stubborn on the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! A decade later and its still a problem, but you edit ~/.gitk instead (and lime worked for me)